# Change text every 3 sec or go to the next text using left / right arrows - bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change a text on a table every 3 secondes with the possibility to go to the next text or going back to the previous one with left and right arrows ( the `<i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-3x"></i>`  are the arrows using font-awesome)

I think JQuery would be the best for that and I don t know it very well.

If possible, I would like to change the background as well at the same time than the text.

Thanks everyone! :)

Here is my code:
(only the first text is here. I don t know where to put the other ones)

```
<div class="row quotes">
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="middle"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-3x"></i></a></td>
          <td align="center" valign="middle"><p>BlaBlaBlaBla Text 1</p></td>
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-3x"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.quotes {
color:#FFF;
background: url("../img/quotes/qo-2.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
padding:60px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect time to use the bootstrap carousal with an interval of 3 seconds per slide.